# Need a 3rd party tool for AFP Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, afp

I have a client that has a mixed environment of Windows XP and 7, and Mac Lion and Snow Leopard.  We recently upgraded their server from Windows 2k3 to Windows 2k8 and realized Microsoft has dropped support for SFM and AFP.  I have found ExtremeZ-IP Server, but its $1,500 for 10 users.  I know you get what you pay for but there has to be something else out there that is a bit cheaper that does the same thing?  Any thoughts or ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a Windows 2k3 server back to the domain, enable SFM and have it point to the new Windows 2008 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use SMB?  From the Mac - smb://WindowsServerName
(OS X supports SMB natively which is part of the reason MS dropped SFM/AFP - there's no real need for it anymore).

Comment: The reason they dont want to use SMB is because it is incredibly slow to connect and they have to reconnect every time they turn their Mac's on.

Comment: You're the first person I've encountered that I've heard that from.  I suggest you look over your settings including SMB settings on the server and Mac.